# How do I get the generated AST from lemon?

Tags: parsing, lemon

How do I get the root node of the AST (abstract syntax tree) from [lemon](https://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/)? I have tried using `%extra_argument { Node *rootNode }` and using the following code to return the root node object.

```
program ::= statements(A). { rootNode = A; }
```

But root node the root node in the main parse function stays empty.

Here is the main parse function.

```cpp
Node parse()
{
    void* parser = ParseAlloc(malloc);
    int token;
    Node astRoot;

    while (token = yylex())
    {
        Parse(parser, token, yytext, &astRoot);
    }

    Parse(parser, 0, NULL, &astRoot);
    ParseFree(parser, free);

    return astRoot;
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be clearer about how you used the extra argument and the problem you encountered. Include an actual code sample, or even better a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`rootNode` is a pointer. You're updating the local variable `rootNode`. Try dereferencing it when you copy:

```
program ::= statements(A). { *rootNode = *A; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didn't work the ```astRoot``` object stays as an "empty" object.